# Open set for the line segments from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, \frac{1}{n})$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be the union of line segments from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1/n)$, including the line from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 0)$. The topology for $X$ is all the open sets $U$ where $U$ is open if $U$ intersected with every line individually in $X$ is open (each line here has the subspace topology).
>
> Prove that this is a valid topology, and give an example of a set that is open in this topology, but not open when $X$ has the subspace topology.

$X$ is in this topology since we are just intersection every line with itself, and given the subspace topology, each line is open in itself. So the empty set is also in the topology. For finite intersections, I think all the open sets are disjoint so all finite intersections are empty. I'm not sure how to do the arbitrary unions.

I can't find any set that's open with this topology, but not the subspace one since they seem like the exact same thing, because it says each line has the subspace topology, and each line is a subset of $X$ itself..

Comment: It is not clear to me that you include the end points of the segments in X or not. Either way, the topology is not the subspace topology. If you include the endpoints then X is a closed bounded subset of the plane so its subspace topology is compact, but the topology you define on X is not compact.

Comment: @user254665 I think he means "each line here has the usual subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$", not subspace topology of X defined here., which implies the lines are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly.

> For finite intersections, I think all the open sets are disjoint so
>   all finite intersections are empty.

This is wrong. $X=\bigcup L_n$, where $L_n$ is open segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,\frac{1}{n})$, in addition, $L_i\cap L_j=\phi$ if $i\ne j$. So by definition, $U$ is open iff $U\cap L_n = u_n$ is open for all n, and $U=\bigcup u_n$.

Take open sets $U,V\subseteq S, U=\bigcup u_n, V=\bigcup v_n, u_n,v_n\subseteq L_n$, then $u_n$,$v_n$ are open implies $(U\cap V)\cap L_n = u_n\cap v_n$ is open, thus $U\cap V = \bigcup(u_n\cap v_n)$ is open.$U\cup V$ can be proved similar as above, replacing $u_n\cap v_n$ with $u_n\cup v_n$.

> give an example of a set that is open in this topology, but not open
>   when X has the subspace topology.

Noting the given topology only preserves the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ along each line segments. We can exploit this.

Comment: Do note that we can't just take any open line segment from $X$ for the counterexample. For example, if the origin is not included, and I took the (open) line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, then this is actually open in $X$ (it could be thought of as the intersection of $X$ and the open plane $\{(x,y):y>\frac{2x}{3}\}$, for example).

Comment: @JoeyZou  I think open line segment from (0,0) to (1,1) is a counterexample. It is just the segment of $n=1$, intersection with itself is itself, while intersection with other $n$ is $\phi$. It's clearly open in X. but any segment is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. anyway the counter example should be take from some $L_n$. I've edit my answer.

Comment: We want a set which is open under the special topology given but not open in the subspace topology, so the line being open in $X$ means that we *don't* want it as a counterexample.

Comment: @JoeyZou I mean open in X under the given topology. but not when X has the usual subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Under usual subspace topology, taking a point from the segment, any open ball around the point contains point outside the segment.

Comment: Actually, for each point $x$ on $L_1$ there is a minimum distance $r_x$ from $x$ to any other line segment. Then the set of points in $X$ whose distance from $x$ is less than $r_x$ is open in $X$ under the subspace topology and is contained entirely in $L_1$.


Now, the ball of radius $r_x$ around $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will contain points outside $X$, but that doesn't matter, since we're discussing the subspace topology. What we care about in the subspace topology is the ball in $X$ and not the ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology

Comment: @JoeyZou OK. I misunderstood it. Then for discrete set of $n$ ($\mathbb{N}$,$\mathbb{Q}^+$,etc.), I cannot find a counter example. Since any open set $U$ of $X$ is an union of discrete segments, and we can easily construct an open set $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that $V\cup S=U$. For contigious set of $n$ ( $\mathbb{R}$, or a contigious subset of $\mathbb{R}$), the construction should be easy, like $\{(x,y)| \frac{x}{3} \le y \le \frac{x}{2}, \frac{1}{3} < x < \frac{2}{3}\}$

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample, consider a set whose intersection with each line is an open line segment containing the origin, but whose lengths can be made arbitrarily small. (For example, including a segment of length $1/n$ on the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1/n)$). This set would not be open, since no ball around the origin would fit in that set.

EDIT: A much simpler solution: just take an open interval on the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$, such as the line between $(1/3,0)$ and $(2/3,0)$. Then it doesn't matter whether the endpoints are in the set or not. :)

Comment: I think this is open in the subspace topology as well, since if you take this set, and intersect it with $X$, you get this set back and it is considered open by the subspace topology

Comment: A set whose intersection with $X$ is itself is simply a subset of $X$.

By subspace topology, you do mean treating $X$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, right? If so, then saying that the set is open means it can be written as $X\cap U$ for some $U$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes. I think I might have misunderstood your counter-example

Comment: But X is the union of line segments, by subspace topology each segment is open, so $(0,0)\notin X$

Comment: Okay, it was not clear from the question whether the line segments were closed or not (if not, then the origin need not be in $X$). I will edit the answer shortly.